# Death during war/combat and Moksha

Tags: moksha, war, swarga

Normally in Ramayana and Bharatha story telling, it is said that death during war is sacred: Veera Maranam.
Question is, is there any scriptural references to say the death in combat is considered sacred and any statements which says whether individual attains Moksha or goes to Swarga.

Comment: May not be so in general. Do Bhishma and Duryodhana deserve to get the same moksha?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Lord Krishna says to Arjuna in the *Bhagavad Gita*, Chapter 2, verses 31-32 and 37 (Swami Nikhilananda translator):

> 31. Considering also, your own dharma, you should not waver; to a kshatriya nothing is better than a righteous war.
> 32. Happy indeed are the kshatriyas, O Partha, to whom comes such a war, offering itself unsought, opening the gate to heaven.
> 33. If you are killed in battle, you will go to heaven; if you win, you will enjoy the earth. Therefore arise, O son of Kunti, resolved to fight.

Comment: Thanks. It says heaven. So, considered as sacred. I guess moksha is not guaranteed.